# Are Branch.io links no longer authorized in Facebook Messenger and Instagram?

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-messenger, branch.io

Since few weeks, Branch.io links seem to be banned from Facebook Messenger and Instagram when I tried to send some.
I made some research about it but without any success.

Any statement from Branch or update about this issue?

Do you also encounter this problem on your links guys?

Thanks

Comment: (Not using that service, but just observed that my desktop browser ad- and tracking blocker already blocks access to their base domain … probably says something about how good of an idea it is to use such services in the first place. You are going to keep your stuff from working for potentially _a lot_ of users that pay a little more attention to their online privacy …)

Comment: @misorude thanks for pointing out this. In our case, Branch is mainly use for the referral program which provides a very convenient service to do it.